# Generate json containing float numbers following 0

Tags: php, json, string, laravel, api

I've been searching lots of forums and question, but unable to find any find any answer for this.

in simple words is it possible to create a json response like this in php:

```
{
    "Balance": 1.200
}
```

`1.2000` not being a string.

Comment: Why should one need the 0's?

Comment: I'm integrating an API and they want our responses to be like this.

Comment: you can but last 00 will be lost, means you will get "Balance":1.2

Comment: Are you sure it is not _one thousand and two hundred_? Otherwise it doesn't make any sense to format like 1.200 or 1.200000. @BunkerBoy that is exactly what OP is asking

Comment: That is  the problem i'm facing. That's why i asked the direct question that "Is it possible"?

Comment: Store the number as a string then: `{ "Balance": "1.200"}`

Comment: @bub

Yes, i'm sure.

Comment: @Veve had the same idea but OP doesn't want it as string

Comment: API guys don't accept my response saying it can't be string. They need it to be 1.200 without being a string. They can't seem to accept the fact that it's not possible. So i came here to experts.

Comment: If you want to show leading 0s, you need to use a string. Numbers are never stored or displayed in a computer with leading 0s. However, if you really want to output a response like that there's no reason you can't do something like: `$number = '1.200'; echo '{"Balance": ' . $number . '}';`. However, this kind of defeats the point.

Comment: Then if it's not what @bub suggested they're doing it wrong, and you won't be abble to send them an integer with unnecessary trailing zeros, it doesn't make any sense for an integer to have them.

Comment: @Kanav can you able to calculate every time that how may digit you want after decimal like in above case you have to allow 3 digit after decimal ?

Comment: if you can so, in this case number_format() can be used

Comment: @Bunker Boy They want 4 digits after decimal, but using `number_format` makes it a string

Comment: no try this  <?php  var_dump((double)number_format(1.2011, 4));

Comment: a simple one in php

Comment: @BunkerBoy If you `var_dump` , it's a string: http://ideone.com/dHbcWf

Comment: check updated one with typecast, you can type cast for that with float or double

Comment: I didn't see any link of the updated one. Did you forget to attach it, or meant something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [the result they want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251019/generate-json-containing-float-numbers-following-0/42251393#comment71660295_42251019) is not *one thousand and two hundred* [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251019/generate-json-containing-float-numbers-following-0/42251393#comment71660104_42251019) by [bub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4429015/bub), then you won't be abble to send them an integer with unnecessary trailing zeros, it doesn't make any sense for an integer to have them.

If it would be possible, how would you store the number of zeros within the integer value? AFAIK it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will need to tweak the JSON string on your own. E.g.:

1. Convert the value of Balance from number `1.2` to string `"@@1.2@@"` before generating JSON string.
2. Generate the JSON string
3. Use PHP to replace in the string all occurences of `"@@[whatever_number]@@"` with `[whatever_number_with_trailing_zeroes]`

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, *everything* is possible, but your JSON won't be valid (although most JSON parsers won't complain) - just store your 'padded' balance as string, then post-process it to remove its quotes:

```
// Make sure your data contains Balance in the format you need, as string
$your_data = array('Balance' => '1.200', 'foo' => 'bar');

// Encode your data the regular way
$json = json_encode($your_data);

echo "Before: $json"; // Before: {"Balance":"1.200","foo":"bar"}

// remove quotes around balance instances in your JSON
$fixed_json = preg_replace('/Balance":(\s*)"(.*?)"/', 'Balance":$2$1', $json);

echo "After: $fixed_json"; // After: {"Balance":1.200,"foo":"bar"}
```

Of course, keep in mind that this will remove quotes from all `Balance` values in your JSON no matter the level.

The bigger question is who, in his right mind, would require you to send invalid JSON to their API?

Comment: lol. i loved your last line. But yeah there are companies who are not aware about this.

Comment: One would assume that if they have people competent enough to implement an API, these people should know what's valid JSON and what's not, especially since they chose the format in the first place.
Oh well, the above code should solve your problem but feel free to rub their noses with their API being crap n' all ;)